# MYSQL Query - Sort by Date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to set up a query that will search a MYSQL database and only pull in the rows from the database who's expiry_date is after todays date.

I would also like to be able to work out how many days or weeks there are remaining from todays date to the expiry date of the rows in the database that match the above query.

I think that in order to get the current date I would have to set up a variable of $date = time(); which I will then later be able to use to compare against the expiry_date column in the database. However I am now stumped as what to do to achieve the required result. I'm not exactly a PHP noob but I'm not an expert either, so please go easy on me ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this can and should all be done in the query ie `WHERE expiry_date >NOW()` and `DATEDIFF(expiry_date,NOW())` thats 90% done for you

Comment: and the weeks or days remaining you will get with computed columns and the help of [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), i.e `TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, NOW(), expiry_date) as weeks_remaining`.

Answer (score 0):

If the Column you want to check is a DATE(TIME), try

```
$sql="SELECT column FROM table WHERE expiry_date > CURDATE()";
```

If you saved the UNIX timestamp, you can simply use

```
$sql="SELECT column FROM table WHERE expiry_date > '".time()."'";
```

If you use the first with "NOW()" or the second, you'll proably get results for the current day.
If this is not acceptable, try "mktime(0, 0, 0)" instead of time();

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
$query = "select timestampdiff(days,'$exipry_date','$now')";
```